# Vlook up get data from another sheet based on account value

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to create a macro for sending emails from outlook. I have few edits to be done with the raw data for that i have given codes.

Since i m new to VBA i do not know how to use the Vlookup function and also i m not very well versed in using vlookup in excel too :( I am trying to get the data from Master data(Sheet name)-Col A has Account & Col B has values. I want code to get the values of Col B if Col A in there in the Email output sheet.

Master Data sample

```
Account Value
803     A
691     B
8010    C
```

I want to copy the values in the col I of the Email output sheet if the account number matches in the Col A.Can you help?

Col A   Col I

```
Account Value
803     Copy values from Master data depending on Account Value
691     Copy values from Master data depending on Account Value
8010    Copy values from Master data depending on Account Value
```

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A2,MasterDataSheet!A:B,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks... can you help me with the vba code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code, Im trying not use default VLOOKUP Function on vba, but use a logic behind that function to know how VLOOKUP works

```vb
With Sheets("Master Data")
    i1 = 2
    Do While Sheets("Email Output").Cells(i1, 1).Value <> vbNullString
        i2 = 2
        Do While .Cells(i2, 1).Value <> vbNullString
            If Sheets("Email Output").Cells(i1, 1).Value = .Cells(i2, 1).Value Then
                Sheets("Email Output").Cells(i1, 2).Value = .Cells(i2, 2).Value
                Exit Do
            End If
            i2 = i2 + 1
        Loop
        i1 = i1 + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this code. it is getting the values from the master data correctly.. but to the Col B. I want the data to be copied to Col I. Can you help me?

Comment: just replace order of column that you are willing to X: `Sheets("Email Output").Cells(i1, X).Value = .Cells(i2, 2).Value` , in your case column I has order 9, So the code will look like : `Sheets("Email Output").Cells(i1, 9).Value = .Cells(i2, 2).Value`

Comment: Thanks a lot Agung